# Streaming media plugin plays audio only in fullscreen

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I created ionic test project and add streaming media plugin. I want to stream audio when i click button and i did it but problem is that this audio only plays in fullscreen. So can anyone help me? I set fullscreen option to false but it doesn’t work. Platform android.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem and couldn't find any solution online.

Comment: As i find out this plugin's fullscreen option doesn't work on android. I had to use other plugin